# How to convert time interval into number of years?

Tags: sql

How can I convert a time interval in date format (i.e.  "2275 days")  into number of years?

When I divide it by 365 it becomes something like ("6 days 5 hours 32 minutes 44 seconds"). whereas I want to return "6.23 year" or just "6.23".

Comment: show some code please

Comment: `select cast(whatever as real)/365`

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?